# automatically refresh a chart in a vba userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

so im working on a project , and one of the tasks that i have to accomplish is make a chart automatically update itself (every 10 minutes for exemple) without intervenience from the user.

[image]
The code :

As you can see , when I enter a new set of data into the worksheet , it does not appear in the chart , but if close the program and re-execute it , the new set of data appears.
I tried the Ontime method but it did not work for me .
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to paste in your code as text, not a link to an image of your code.